# Selenium NoSuchElementException Drop Down Menu

Tags: java, python, selenium, web-crawler, nosuchelementexception

How can I get around the NoSuchElementException error message using Selenium in Python? I am trying to select a report type from a drop down menu and after running this code:

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

 driver = webdriver.Chrome()

 driver.get("https://examplehtml.com/gims/app/reports")

 ##Report type

 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportType"]').send_keys("Power 
 Report")
```

This inserts the word "Power Report" but it does not select and move the page forward as it would if I manually selected the the report type and I think it's because of the NoSuchElementException error. Why is the element not being found and how can I get around this error. I'm fairly new to Selenium so any advice would help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add html of the element your are trying to find ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the html since the site's access is restricted @Navarasu

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use Select class that you import.
So if your HTML look like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Power Report</option>
  <option value="2">Other Report</option>
</select>
```

.. then I would try this code:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reportType"]')
Select(e).select_by_value('1')
```

.. in case of that the dropdown element is HTML select element.

Comment: I tried your method, but it isn't working for me. I've also tried to "SendKeys" and use the "click" method, but I get an "Unresolved reference" error when using either of these.

Comment: I just updated my original post. You need to use _value_ attribute of _option_ element in select_by_value function. If this won't work then I guess, without your HTML we cannot do more @Jelena

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure, the element you trying to find is visible. Selenium cannot work on the invisible elements.
If the element you want is in a drop-down menu, first you need to drop the menu down. Then, try to find the element again.